# Find all users within a thread of gmail API

Tags: google-api, gmail-api

I am using the gmail API to get recent hangouts messages/threads. But I can't find a way to view the recipient address. The only field in payload.headers is 'From'

code:

`curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer **accessToken**' 'https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/threads/**threadId**?q=is%3Achat'`

response:

```
{
"id": "xxx",
"historyId": "1008967",
"messages": [{
    "id": "xxx",
    "threadId": "xxx",
    "labelIds": [
        "CHAT"
    ],
    "snippet": "+Harry Howard",
    "historyId": "1008953",
    "internalDate": "1481641738948",
    "payload": {
        "partId": "",
        "mimeType": "text/html",
        "filename": "",
        "headers": [{
            "name": "From",
            "value": "xxx"
        }],
        "body": {
            "size": 13,
            "data": "K0hhcnJ5IEhvd2FyZA=="
        }
    },
    "sizeEstimate": 100
}]
}
```

In the case of emails, there is a 'To' field ( and sometimes cc etc).

FYI: I am using node-gmail-api npm module but just testing this with curl

Answer (score -2):

Use `Users.threads:list` to find all users within a thread. See an example [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/list#examples).

**HTTP request**

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userId/threads
```

This request requires authorization with at least one of the following scopes

- https://mail.google.com/
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.metadata

Response

If successful, this method returns a response body with the following structure:

```
{
  "threads": [
    users.threads Resource
  ],
  "nextPageToken": string,
  "resultSizeEstimate": unsigned integer
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Have you actually executed this query to find all the users within a thread? Every response i have got back does not have this data. 

Do you maybe have an example of the actual request url and response JSON that you used to get the result?

Thank you

Comment: you can't get users via list option https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/list